# After Code Signing for Gatekeeper: cannot longer access keychain items for my app

Tags: xcode, code-signing, osx-gatekeeper

I want to code sign my Mac software to make it ready for Gatekeeper and OS X Lion.
So I changed to the build settings in Xcode and selected my Developer ID certificate. Building my project was successfully.
But if I run this new app I cannot longer access the keychain items of the app!
If I remove code signing everythings works ok.

Anybody knows a solution for that problem?

Comment: It looks like that is a bug in 10.8 and 10.7.5. There are several threads in Apple´s developer forum about that problem. You can fix that problem if you set **--timestamp=none** to **other signing flags** in your build settings. But this is not recommend.

Comment: I have a very similar issue, seems to have been caused by running the same app signed two different ways... dont know how to undo it now.